# Notepad++: como não escapar o backslash \

Tags: csv, notepad++

Esta talvez seja uma dúvida trivial. Mas como fazer para o Notepad++ **não** escapar o *backslash* \ ?

Por exemplo, se eu salvar um arquivo .csv com o conteúdo `A\032` o notepad++ escapa o backslash e interpreta a parte \032 como um texto ao invés de um caractere especial.

Comment: já tentou \\ ? duas contrabarras?

Comment: @LuizRossi sim, aí ele escapa as duas barras, e fica \\\\032.

Comment: não consegui reproduzir o erro, pode ser a codificação do arquivo então, veja se no menu 'formatar' não é questão de codificação...

Comment: @LuizRossi O que você chama de reproduzir o erro? Se você está enxergando \032 ao invés de [sub] ou nada, o erro aconteceu, pois \032 não é um caractere visível.

Comment: @CarlosCinelli, como verificas a reprodução do erro? O ficheiro é criado no Notepad e depois salvas como .csv?

Comment: @Cold, crie o .csv com o notepad++ e depois abra no excel, por exemplo. Se no excel aparecer \032 quer dizer que o backslash foi escapado, que é o que eu não quero que aconteça.

Comment: Yah, tens toda razão, eu já tentei e deu este "erro". Existe algum outro aplicativo, além do excel, para testarmos isso?

Comment: @Cold dá para testar em qualquer linguagem de programação que leia csv, como R ou Python.

Comment: @CarlosCinelli, que carater deveria aparecer em vez do texto não interpretado?

Comment: @Cold No notepad++ apareceria SUB, no excel uma setinha.

Comment: Tente fazer o processo reverso pra ver se é mesmo isso. Acredito que poderás perceber que caractere.